# Using a setter as a parameter in C#? (Maybe with delegate?)

Tags: c#, delegates, try-catch, setter, func

We're working on an API for some hardware and I'm trying to write some tests for it in C#. try-catch blocks for repetitive tasks were making my code bloated and repetitive so for getters I was able to wrap like this:

```
TestGetter(Func<int> method, double expectedVal)
{
    int testMe = 0;
    try
    {
        testMe = method();
        PassIfTrue(testMe == expectedVal);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         Fail(e.Message);
    }
}
```

So I query the hardware for some known value and compare. I can call with:

```
TestGetter( () => myAPI.Firmware.Version, 24); //Or whatever.
```

Which works quite well. But I'm not sure how to do the same with setters. Ie to ensure that the API actually set a value (and doesn't timeout or whatever when I try to set). I'd like to pass the setter to the test method and invoke it in there.

Bonus question: Is there a way to do this with a generic type? There are some custom types defined in the API and I'm not sure of a good way to write these test wrappers for them without writing a new overloaded method for every type. Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the getter and the setter to the function:

```
void TestSetter<T>(Func<T> getter, Action<T> setter, T value)
{
    try
    {
        setter(value);
        PassIfTrue(EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(getter(), value));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         Fail(e.Message);
    }       
}
```

This sets the value, then gets it and compares to the value passed to the setter.

You'd have to call it like:

```
TestSetter(() => myAPI.Firmware.Version, v => myAPI.Firmware.Version = v, 24);
```

Comment: This is a compiler error unfortunately since it doesn't ensure that `==` is defined for type `T`. You could cast to dynamic and test that way but it may fail runtime if its not defined.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks - Fixed ;)  I'd recommend using this approach vs. `Object.Equals` as it tends to be safer in general.

Comment: Excellent thank you! I have a few followups, if you don't mind. Sorry if these are basic (I'm fairly new to C# and OOP in general). What is the point of the <T> after the name of the function in its declaration? Why not just "TestSetter(Func<T> getter, ...)"? And when I call it what exactly am I doing by calling "v => myAPI.Firmware.Version = v" what exactly is v in there? Feel free to just point me to further reading if good documentation already exists. :)

Comment: @Gemini That's how you defined a generic method.  For the second, "v" represents the argument passed to the function (defined by the delegate). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can make them generic like Reeds, but you need to use different comparison methods:

```
    public static void TestGetter<T>(Func<T> method, T expectedVal)
    {       
        try
        {
            T actual = method();
            PassIfTrue(expectedVal.Equals(actual));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Fail(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static void TestSetter<T>(Action setMethod, Func<T> getMethod, T expectedVal)
    {
        try
        {
            setMethod();
            T actual = getMethod();
            PassIfTrue(expectedVal.Equals(actual));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Fail(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

You could also pass in a Comparer action to test them if you don't think the `Equals` method would work for the expected types.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'll ask you the same followups as Reed, if you don't mind: What is the point of the <T> after the name of the function in its declaration? Why not just "TestSetter(Func<T> getter, ...)"? And when I call it what exactly am I doing by calling "v => myAPI.Firmware.Version = v" what exactly is v in there? Feel free to just point me to further reading if good documentation already exists. :)

Comment: T has to be defined, if you try that, you'll get an error "namespace or type 'T' cannot be found" or something like that. In his example, v is the value parameter, mine does not have that. His uses V to both do the setting, and the check where my code has an `expectedVal` parameter.